# Textbox "Like" Search

Tags: ms-access, search, textbox, vba

I have a form that I want to search for anything containing what is entered into a textbox. Right now the search only picks up data that matches exactly (ie `MDD`), but I want it to capture anything containing the searched item automatically (ie `*MDD*`)

Ideally I would like a user to enter what they are searching for and get anything that contains that search.

The code I wrote (that partially works) is:

`

```
If Me.tbIni = "" Or IsNull(Me.tbIni) Then
    stCriteria = ""
Else
        If InStr(1, Me.tbIni, "LIKE ") Then
        stCriteria = "CURQCDB.DT_ini '" & Me.tbIni & "'"
    Else
            stCriteria = "CURQCDB.DT_ini = '" & Me.tbIni & "'"
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for `*MDD*` instead of `MDD`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead.  I also took the liberty of sanitizing the input a bit so that it properly handles double and single quotes:

```
If Me.tbIni = "" Or IsNull(Me.tbIni) Then
    stCriteria = ""
Else
    stCriteria = "CURQCDB.DT_ini LIKE ""*" & Replace(Me.tbIni, """", """""") & "*"""
End If
```